A custom python dataclass is interacting with a function in a strange way and outputting a TypeError: 'Message' object is not callable
I have two files:
File 1: Takes a text file of a certain format and reformats in a way I prefer
# Dataframe_maker.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
import re

# Defined a class


class Message:
    sender: str
    date: str
    time: str
    content: str
    isreply: bool
    isreact: bool

# This function takes a block of text in a specific format and returns a Message object

def parse_message(Message_Block: str) -> Message:
    lines = Message_Block.split('\n')
    sender = lines[2][20:]
    date = lines[2][:10]
    time = lines[2][11:19]
    content = lines[4]
    isreply = '➜ Replying to' in content
    isreact = bool(re.search(r'Laughed at “|Loved “|Questioned “|Emphasised “|Liked “|Disliked “', content))
    
    return Message(sender=sender, date=date, time=time, content=content, isreply = isreply, isreact = isreact)

# I have real addresses here of course

file_path_read = 'filepathRead' 
file_path_write = 'filepathWrite' 

with open(file_path_read, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file_read: 
    data = file_read.read()

# Each message was seperated by this string, and the first message was empty so that is removed

message_blocks = data.split('----------------------------------------------------')
message_blocks.pop(0)

messages: List[Message] = [parse_message(block) for block in message_blocks]

with open(file_path_write, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_write:
    for Message in messages:
        file_write.write(f"{Message.sender}, {Message.date}, {Message.time}, {Message.content}, {Message.isreply}, {Message.isreact}\n")

# A function that is not used in this file, but is here so I can import it into other files. It takes each line of the output file of this code and converts it back into a Message object

def parse_line(line) -> Message:
    parts = line.strip().split(', ')
    sender, date, time, content, isreply, isreact = parts
    return Message(sender=sender, date=date, time=time, content=content, isreply=isreply, isreact=isreact)

File 2: This is just a test to see if i can actually read the file I created and turn it back into a list of Message objects in a few short lines. The string finding code is just a simple test
from Dataframe_maker import parse_line, Message

file_path = 'filepathRead'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
messages = [parse_line(line) for line in lines]

# Test begins here

given_string = 'First off, it is important to note that '

for Message in messages:
    if not Message.isreact and not Message.isreply:
        text = Message.content
        if given_string in text:
            index = messages.index(Message)
            length = len(text)
            print(f'The {index}th message is {length} characters long')

The problem I get when I run file 2 is:

It calls a problem in line 7 of file 2 (defining the List of Message objects)
Within that line it calls a problem within the parse_line function
In the function (going back to file 1) it calls a problem in the final line of the function which is the return value of that function, where it returns the input as a Message object
It says TypeError: 'Message' object is not callable

I am not a proficient coder by any means, and this is a hobby project where I am analysing a group chat I share with some friends. I understand what that TypeError means, but to my knowledge the dataclasses in python are callable so I am confused. Any help is appreciated
Edit:
Here is the exact error message (file address changed for privacy):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FileAddress_file2", line 7, in <module>
    messages = [parse_line(line) for line in lines]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "fileAddress_file2", line 7, in <listcomp>
    messages = [parse_line(line) for line in lines]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "fileAddress_file1", line 48, in parse_line
    return Message(sender=sender, date=date, time=time, content=content, isreply=isreply, isreact=isreact)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Message' object is not callable


You're trying to have Message mean two things at once: from Dataframe_maker import parse_line, Message and for Message in messages

Please include the exact error message. Don't paraphrase it

What does "calls a problem" mean?

Why aren't you using the @dataclass decorator?

I guess I dont understand how to note that something is a specific datatype, which is why I am saying 'for a Message datatype in the list messages'. What should I replace this with ?

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

Class names live in the same namespace as everything else; you're rebinding the name Message to something other than the class it originally referred to. Use a different name:
with open(file_path_write, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_write:
    for message in messages:
        file_write.write(f"{message.sender}, {message.date}, {message.time}, {message.content}, {message.isreply}, {message.isreact}\n")


I did previously, but got the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fileAddress_file2", line 7, in 
messages = [parse_line(line) for line in lines]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "fileAddress_file2", line 7, in 
messages = [parse_line(line) for line in lines]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "fileAddress_file1", line 47, in parse_line
sender, date, time, content, isreply, isreact = parts
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 6)

That's an entirely separate problem, unrelated to your reuse of the name Message.
